# Why does "Truecaller" appear in my Google My Activity section so much?

Tags: google, google-search-history

I have recently found about about Google's "My Activity" page; a very useful place that lets you see/permanently delete your search history. Every time I go on the page, though, I see a lot of "Truecaller: Caller ID, block fraud & scam calls" even though I'm sure I did not personally install an extension called Truecaller.

Can somebody please tell me what Truecaller is, and if I should be worried? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My Activity also shows activity from outside your browser, but devices connected to your Google account such as smartphones. if you have Truecaller app installed, this will come up here